# Java supposedly works with international variables. Why can't I make it work?

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization

I have always wanted to use greek variables.  I've tried both Chinese and Greek.  I have tried
in emacs and Eclipse.  Saved in utf-8.  Nothing works.

```
public class I18NTest {
    private static double π = 3.14159265358979；
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(π);
    }

}
```

There is a compiler error on the line with the pi.

Comment: "Nothing works" doesn't tell us anything about what you're seeing, or indeed how you're trying to compile it.

Comment: @JonSkeet A copy/paste revealed a visually nonobvious trivial but interesting error.

Comment: @Dov Please try to keep answers out of the question description; though it's good that you were able to figure out a nontrivial issue on your own.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that for whatever reason you're using the wrong character (`\65307`) for the semicolon at the end of your constant definition. Replace that with the correct character and it works fine.

Comment: And the equal sign was also weird.

Comment: @Dov It, at least, translated correctly when you pasted into the SO box. I suspect that the compiler was giving you a very specific error message with an arrow pointing to the problematic character and even telling you which code point it was.

Answer (score 4):

If you save the file as *UTF-8* and have the standard semi-colon(`;`) character at the end of declaration of "pi", it works just fine in Eclipse. The problem seems to be with the `semi-colon` character.

[image: International Character]